# Why does 2^-1 mod 17 equal 9?

Tags: modulo

For an exam i have to calculate some elliptic curve stuff (probably not important for this question) where I had to calculate:

2^-1 mod 17 (according to wolfram alpha the result is 9)

Now I don't have any clue why the result is 9?
Could someone explain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's giving you the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse):

> In modular arithmetic, the modular multiplicative inverse of an
>   integer a modulo m is an integer x such that
>
> ```
> ax ≡ 1 (mod m)
> ```

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)

In other words, it's the number x such that `2*x % 17 == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

According to wolfram alpha, we can write;
2^-1 mod 17 => 17 = 2 * 9 - 1
so 9 is the Answer